# How to reproduce with a manual query: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: failed to find conversion function from "unknown" to integer;

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, amazon-redshift, driver, dropwizard

I recently added a maven dependency to a Dropwizard project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
            <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.45.1069</version>
        </dependency>
```

which is replacing the `org.postgresql.Driver` previously used, and since then some of my queries are returning

```
! Causing: org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToCreateStatementException: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: failed to find conversion function from "unknown" to integer;
```

I suspect I might have dozens of queries that will need adapting to work with the new driver.

Because I don't want to have to restart my server every time I want to test whether a change to a query fixes the problem, I want to run the queries manually against the Redshift DB, so that I can quickly identify the part of the query that needs fixing.

My problem: I cannot reproduce the error when running the query manually from inside an IntelliJ DB Console. I even downloaded the JAR of the Amazon Redshift Driver from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html (I downloaded this one: https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.45.1069/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.45.1069.jar) and used it to set up a new DB connection in IntelliJ. But still, running the exact same query manually from the IntelliJ DB Console won't give me the error.

Can anyone think of what configuration might be causing the query to give an error when run by the server compared to running it manually from the Console ? And how to get it to either stop throwing the exception on the server or start causing the same error when run in a Console ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the issue lies somewhere between JDBI and the Amazon Redshift Driver. In any case, here's a fix that solved the problem for now:

For a query like this:

```
    //language=PostgreSQL
public static final String MY_QUERY = "" +
    "WITH my_table(someid, groupname) AS (\n" +
    "    SELECT :someId, :groupName\n" +
    ")\n" +
    "SELECT 'something'\n" +
    "FROM my_table mt\n" +
    "FULL OUTER JOIN another_table at ON at.accountid = mt.someid AND at.groupname = mt.groupname";
```

Adding `\\:\\:int` got rid of the error:

```
    //language=PostgreSQL
public static final String MY_QUERY = "" +
    "WITH my_table(someid, groupname) AS (\n" +
    "    SELECT :someId\\:\\:int, :groupName\\:\\:text\n" +
    ")\n" +
    "SELECT 'something'\n" +
    "FROM my_table mt\n" +
    "FULL OUTER JOIN another_table at ON at.accountid = mt.someid AND at.groupname = mt.groupname";
```